# Display toast notification not shows when javascript value passes as Stringbuilder?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, toast

this is my c# On Timer Load function in which i use StringBuilder to pass value in javascript function

```
ds = du.returnDataSet("proc", "READ_PANIC_DATA", Parameters, DbTypes, ParameterTypes, values, Lengths);        
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
StringBuilder Panicdata = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Panicdata.Append("&nbsp;");

    Panicdata.Append("&nbsp;" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["VEHICLE_NO"].ToString());
    Panicdata.Append("&nbsp;" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SERVER_TIME"].ToString() + "</td>");
}    

string popupScript = "";

dt = ds.Tables[0];

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    popupScript = "<script language='javascript'>" +
    "showSuccessToast(" + Panicdata.ToString() + ");" +
    "</script>";
}
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "popupScript", popupScript);
```

and below code is my javscript function on aspx page:

```
function showSuccessToast(data) {
            $().toastmessage('showSuccessToast', data);
    }
```

The data comes from sql server through Timer like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="brij" runat="server" OnLoad="brij_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="praveen" runat="server" Interval="5000">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:Panel ID="sharique" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Toast Popup not displayed......**

Comment: any answer please....

Comment: What is `$().toastmessage`? Have you debugged? Any errors in the console? does `showSuccessToast` actually get called?